# Zipping a list with a list of lists in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, zip

is there a way to zip a list with a list of lists? So for example you have the two lists:

```
lst1 = ['food', 'drinks', 'sports']
lst2 = [['hamburger', 'beer', 'football'], ['cheeseburger', 'wine', 'tennis']]
```

And then as a result u would get:

```
[{'food':'hamburger', 'drinks':'beer', 'sports':'football'},     
{'food':'cheeseburger', 'drinks':'wine', 'sports':'tennis'}]
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Combine dictionary construction and list comprehension:

```
[dict(zip(lst1, l)) for l in lst2]
```